# Entity model must be converted to System.IDisposable

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I know the `IDisposable` conversion question has been asked a lot of times, however I haven't found any of them dealing with something similar to my situation. I'm working on an Entity Framework REST web service. My server project consists of a first project connected to the database in which I created the model and of another project taking care of the service part (data contracts and so on). My second project includes a reference to the first, however when trying to query the database with `using (var db = new LibraryContext()) {` I get the "type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to System.IDisposable" error. And I don't get why it says this error here while I'm able to use the same line in the other project. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying LibraryContext doesn't implement IDisposable so you can't use it in a using statement. 
So either you don't need the using or you need to make it implement the interface IDisposable

Comment: I simply didn't need it. Thanks.